# Load html from file to nightmare.js

Tags: javascript, testing, nightmare

I could not find any documentation on the following:

With nightmare.js normally I do:

```
let nightmare = Nightmare()
return nightmare
  .goto('www.example.com')
  .evaluate(()=>{ 
  // ...
```

I try to test my code isolated, without any internet connection. Is it possible to load html into nightmare instead of the `goto(url)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the webpage as html page. All dynamic content would not function and depending on the webpage, the saved html page might not be useful for you. But if you are able to save it you should be able to load it.

```
win.loadURL(url[, options])
```

As [documentation](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md) says

The url can be a remote address (e.g. http://) or a path to a local HTML file using the file:// protocol.